# JQuery Dragging Outside Parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using JQuery's draggable(); to make li elements draggable. The only problem is when the element is dragged outside its parent, it doesn't show up. That is, it doesn't leave the confines of its parent div. An example is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo6tC.png - it's as if the z-index for everything else has greater priority (and the element slides under everything).

Here's the code:

```
$('.photoList li').draggable({ 
        distance: 20,
        snap: theVoteBar,
        revert: true,
        containment: 'document'
    });
```

And the li elements are placed in DIVs like this:

```
<div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-wrapper">
            <h2 class="title" style="display:none;">Page 1</h2>
            <ul class="photoList">
                <li>
                    <img class="ui-widget-content" src="photos/1.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm positive the problem is it won't leave its parent container, but I'm not sure what to do to get it out.

Any direction or help would be appreciated GREATLY!

Answer (score 21):

I landed on this page with the exact same problem, and Brendan's answer got me close. Setting the `appendTo` option didn't help, but I was able to resolve my issue by adding `overflow: visible` to the parent of my draggable element. Turns out I was sloppily inheriting hidden from somewhere up the chain.

Side note, it looks like this works because jQuery UI moves the draggable element by dynamically setting positioning relative to the parent - this was new intel for me!

Comment: Came here looking for the solution... curiously appendTo worked for me!

Comment: Can you please post some sample code are the link of jsfiddle etc.?

Comment: Hi Amit,  Look at my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/rahulvaradkar/w8dsz5qk/   Look at line number #1   as <div id="Table_Tree" title="BCP Explorer" style="display:none;overflow: visible">   Change "overflow: scroll" OR "overflow: hidden" and try Dragging the "Boardwalk Farm". You will get the difference.

Answer (score 13):

I had also the same problem.
You can use this option

**containment: $('#divmain')

helper: 'clone'**

respectively for
- define limit area for dropping action
- for shows visible dragged object also outside div parent but inside #divmain

example

```
<div id="divmain">
  <div id="divparentdraggable">
    <div id="divdraggable"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="divparentdroppable">
    <div id="divdroppable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$('divparentdraggable').draggable({ 
...
containment: $('#divmain'),
helper: 'clone',
...
});
```

I hope this help someone.

Comment: The helper: 'clone' option is extremely useful, as I have a ul that must retain overflow: scroll;. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue and this worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a combination of some of the above did it for me.

Set `appendTo: 'body'` and `helper: 'clone'`.
This way a new DOM-Object will be created as child of the body which will be visible everywhere. This way you can drag (and drop) it everywhere you like.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a css issue. Try turning off the revert so it stays put when you drag it to where it is half visible. Then play with the z-index etc in Firebug and see if you can get it showing. It might be a css issue with one of the parent ul or div's with 'overflow: hidden'.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by setting the option:

```
appendTo: 'body'
```

The only side effect to this is if you have styles applied to the item based on it's parent container, those styles won't be present on the helper.