# Drag item outside the scrollable div with jQuery draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I want to have a scrollable div with some items inside, but when I try to drag items outside it, overflow-y: scroll forces them to stay inside, and makes an unwanted horizontal scroll as well... Is there a way around it? Here's the pen to illustrate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOgqQq

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Drag me</div>
</div>

$(".item").draggable();
```

Comment: I think this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656258/jquery-dragging-outside-parent

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted to be ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".container").droppable();
$(".item").draggable();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.item{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Also include jQueryUI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="item">Drag me</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

u can drag outside by removing Overflow

```js
$(".item").draggable();
```

```css
#item {position:absolute;}
.container {
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div  class="item">Drag me</div>
</div>
```

**Otherwise if u want to keep overflow , you use the following method**

```js
$(".item").draggable();
```

```css
#item {position:absolute;}
.container {
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
  <div  class="item">Drag me</div>
```