# jquery ui draggable position relative not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

i wanted to create some icons like windows, but not being able to do so. here is irregular positioned icons [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbaykhvu/24/)

My css works fine if i use simple Draggable function like one :

```
$( ".big_dawg span" ).draggable({

});
```

> Please change height of jsfiddle result to see responsive spans: **[Another DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j8gbyw5q/)**

or if i change position of spans forcefully using this function :

```
 $(".big_dawg span").css("position", "initial");
```

Then it works Exactly as i want but then **.Draggable** isn't working.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633918/714985 you can find a simple example how to set drag and drop. I hope help you.